# js | prevent abuse of log function

Tags: javascript, amazon-waf

I've got a class which runs some logic and in some cases send a log to the backend (as a response to an event).

```
var sendLog = function(message) {
    // xhr here 
};
```

There is an option to detect abuse of this function on the client side? Actually, to stop someone from taking this function and put it in an endless loop.

I tend right now to install kind of a WAF on the backend and block the user while detecting bad behavior. But, I'm wondering if there is an option to block it on the client side (even if partially).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern to prevent API calls abuse client-side is [throttling](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf): it will prevent to a function to be called too often.